# Increment value in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, increment

Does Fortran have a syntax for incrementing a variable or field?

As far as I am aware, Fortran has only the syntax

```
counter = counter + 1
```

For plain variables inside small algorithms that is fine. However, in the context of larger programs this leads to readability problems, e.g.

```
simulationInformation(iSimulatedObject)%numberOfEvaluations = simulationInformation(iSimulatedObject)%numberOfEvaluations
simulationState(iStep)%stateArray(iDimen1,iDimen2,iDimen3,iDimen4) = simulationState(iStep)%stateArray(iDimen1,iDimen2,iDimen2,iDimen4) + 1
```

Here having a `+=` operator would vastly improve readability and reliability; Note the intentional typo in the second example. Quite hard to catch in real code. The first example is an obscured version of actual code from the project I'm working for, that prompted the question, when I realized that the verbose syntax makes recognizing, that the line simply increments a counter, surprisingly non-obvious at first glance.

In the past I've used constructs like

```
#define CHANGE(VAR) VAR = VAR
CHANGE(simulationState(iStep)%jacobian(iDimension1,iDimension1)) + 1
CHANGE(someOtherVerboseThing) * 2
```

but this approach likewise compromises readability of the code; Since it isn't a standard feature, other developers are unlikely to use it when writing their portions of the code, and it will be confusing if they see it. And "other developers" typically includes "me, when I revisit the code two years later".

Hence I am looking for a conventional way to do it, that avoids duplicating the left-hand side of the assignment.